# Overloading dereferencing operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

noGiven a private Member pData

```
private:
    T*    pData; // Generic pointer to be stored
```

Below is the overloaded implementation of * and ->

```
T& operator* ()
{
    return *pData;
}

T* operator-> ()
{
    return pData;
}
```

We call the same from the main as shown below:

```
void main(){
    SP<PERSON> p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    p->Display();
}
```

I cannot understand how -> and "*" operator overloading will work here?
or to be more clear how `p->Display();`  will be interpreted?

Comment: Hint: Always specify the appropriate language tag, otherwise chances are high no one finds your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` operator is special. When it returns an object, it is automatically applied again. If it returns another object it is also applied again, until finally a plain pointer is returned. This is called chaining, the plain pointer is finally dereferenced and the chain stops.

`p->Display()` is therefore interpreted like this:

```
p->Display(); // Compiler sees this
T* tmp = p.operator->(); // First applied operator-> (the one you provided)
tmp->Display(); // since T* is a pointer itself, operator-> (the built-in one for pointers) is applied
```